# Keep Complaining No space even using Tab key

Tags: linux, ssd

I am new to linux. I keep getting complaints about "no space" and I checked my lab server hard drive which should be fairly large enough. The only overloaded one seems the `/dev/nvme0n1p3` (SSD?!). How can I clean it up to free up some space? I don't even know how to check what are the files saved on it. Thanks

[df -hl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTbMU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get the "no space" message, what you mean by "overloaded" and what your disk layout is, but:

First thing you need is the disk-layout. This is what you also see in the `df` output. An example from my system:

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                           32768       1620      31148   5% /run
devtmpfs                     16290444          0   16290444   0% /dev
/dev/sda2                   927862216  484284484  396375428  55% /
tmpfs                        16297532     516776   15780756   4% /dev/shm
cgroup_root                      8192          0       8192   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      523248      36308     486940   7% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                   307531896  191859560  100027564  66% /room/WD_L
```

When a 'no space' message comes, in general, it is the partition with `/tmp` that is full. Might also be `/home` though. In the example from above, there is no separate `/tmp` mount, so `/tmp` will be on root.

The first step would be to clean-up at least some room to be able to work. I normally delete some files in `/tmp`, starting with the oldest. If you do `ls -lt`, the oldest are the last in the list. If that doesn't free-up sufficient space, I delete the oldest log-files in `/var/log`. Note that both `/tmp` and `/var/log` are on `/` in my system.

So, now that we have at least some breathing space, we go looking for the data that can be deleted. In my experience, it is either some run-away process that keeps on logging (and therefore filling-up `/var/log`) or it is `/home` (if that is not on a separate partition). If it is a run-away process that logs, then you need to kill it. Rebooting might help here, but be sure to have at least some space left when you reboot.

If it is in `/home`, you can find the user with the most disk usage with

```
sudo du -sh /home
```

or, if you are the only user on the system, find the biggest usage with

```
du -sh ~/* ~/.??* | sort -h
```

Delete the biggest space wasters (but not the files you want to keep!).

If in the list `~/.local/share/akonadi` is the biggest space-waster, just delete that directory completely.